# Check if QML file has valid syntax

Tags: qt, qml, evaluation

I am using Qt 5.6 with QML. I receive QML content over network, but before I use it I want to verify that the QML syntax is actually valid. I saw that there is a javascript evaluator, but nothing similar for QML specific code.

Anyone done something similar to this?

Comment: Make sure that you trust the source of that QML. It's executable code and can do anything that your application otherwise can do. At the very least use an SSL connection and verify the certificate of the remote.

Comment: @KubaOber It's a trusted source (me), but it is a good point and fair warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load your QML content into a [`QQmlComponent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html) using [`QQmlComponent::loadUrl()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html#loadUrl). Listen to the [`QQmlComponent::statusChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html#statusChanged) signal and get any eventual errors with [`QQmlComponent::errors()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html#errors). It returns a list of [`QQmlError`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlerror.html) objects, from which you can verify what kind of error(s) occurred.

---

EDIT: As [Kuba Ober](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329652/kuba-ober) pointed out in a comment:

> Make sure that you trust the source of that QML. It's executable code and can do anything that your application otherwise can do. At the very least use an SSL connection and verify the certificate of the remote.

Comment: I did not think of that! Thank you 

Comment: It seems that the Error state is never called. I try setting the flag QQmlComponent::CompilationMode::PreferSynchronous, so it might be that it is actually not synchronous (I am not loading qml over network now so the documentation about PreferSynchronous not working for network qml does not apply)

Comment: It actually just stops at QQmlComponent::Status::Loading if there is a syntax error and errors() and errorString() does not report any errors.